# Liquid: ifelse not working and printing var in the body

Tags: html, css, if-statement, liquid

I'm trying to create a home page for a simple blog with HTML and CSS. For the blog posts, I've created 2 types of cards: `blog-card` and `blog-card alt`, one to the left and one to the right, and they are meanted to be alterneted. So I did the following code:

```
{% assign iter = 0 %}
{% for post in site.posts %}
{% increment iter %}
{% assign itermodulo = iter | modulo: 2 %}
{% if itermodulo == 0 %}
<div class="blog-card">
...
</div>

{% else %}
<div class="blog-card alt">
...
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But instead of alternating the card format, all the cards are on the left (following `blog-card`) and the var `iter` is being printed on the screen. What I have to do? Thanks in advace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% assign itermodulo = forloop.index | modulo: 2 %}
  {% if itermodulo == 0 %}
    <div class="blog-card"></div>
  {% else %}
    <div class="blog-card alt"></div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```